# How to resolve an incompatible upper bounds error for method that returns generic Enum

Tags: java, generics, enums

I gave an `interface` to define behavior for `enums` with reverse lookup capability:

```
public interface Enumerable {
    public String getName();
    public <E extends Enum<E>> E getByName(String name);
}
```

Here is an `enum` that `implements` the `interface`:

```
public enum SubMenu implements Enumerable {

    SIMPLE_MENU("An Option");

    private final String name;

    public static final Map<String,SubMenu> lookup = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (SubMenu subMenu : EnumSet.allOf(SubMenu.class)) {
            lookup.put(subMenu.getName(), subMenu);
        }
    }

    private SubMenu(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public final String getName() { return name; }

    public SubMenu getByName(String name) {
        return lookup.get(name);
    }
}
```

When I try to assign the `return` value of `getByName(String name)` to a variable of a specific `enum` type, I get this error: "incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible upper bounds java.lang.Enum,SubMenu". How do I resolve this error?

```
public final List<Enumerable> getSubMenuOptions(final Enumerable subMenu) {

    //Here is where I get the error
    SubMenu sm = subMenu.getByName(subMenu.getName());

    .....
}
```

Comment: Silly question I imagine, but are you sure your compile error is not related instead, to the fact you are declaring a local variable `subMenu` with the same name as your method parameter `subMenu`?

Comment: Hi-- it was typo in my question. My source code in my IDE didn't have that mistake. My question has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enhance the `Enumerable` interface signature with an additional type argument

```
public interface Enumerable<E extends Enum<E>> {

    public String getName();

    public E getByName(String name);    
}
```

and adjust the rest of the code accordingly:

```
public enum SubMenu implements Enumerable<SubMenu> {

    MENU_OPTION_1("An Option"),
    MENU_OPTION_2("Another Option";

    private final String localizedName;

    private SubMenu(final String localizedName){
        this.localizedName = localizedName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.localizedName;
    }

    @Override
    public SubMenu getByName(final String pName) {
        for(SubMenu menu : values()){
            if(menu.name().equals(pName) 
                    || menu.localizedName.equals(pName)){
                return menu;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }    
}

public class ClientClass{

    /**
     * This method can work with SubMenu, if you explicitly exchange the generic E with SubMenu
     */
    public <E extends Enum<E>> E getSubMenuOptions(final Enumerable<E> submenu){
        E sm = submenu.getByName(submenu.getName());

        return sm;
    }
}
```

Comment: So I take it you think the static lookup map is a bad idea too? I am off to give this solution a try. I think this is what I am looking for. I will be back shortly to accept this answer.

Comment: I ignored the Map, because it did exactly the same functionality, that is delivered by each enum on its own. You can easiliy address enum values by their name, just like you would call a static final constant from any class. Anyhow, you can of course implement it, if you feel a benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you pass is of type Enumerable.

The type itself is not generic, it just has a generic method.

The generic method defines that its return type is some (unknown) Enum type.

So when you call `subMenu.getByName(submenu.getName())`, the type of the result is basically "An unknown Enum".

Now you try to assign this to a specific variable of type `SubMenu`. Since "An unknown Enum" may be any Enum in the world, you can't assign it without type casting to a variable of the specific type `SubMenu`. The true type returned may, indeed, be `SubMenu`, but since `Enumerable` is not generic, the compiler has no way of knowing that.